# DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I'm getting an error when trying to setup a datatables with my laravel project.

**DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7**

This is my controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Transaction;
use DataTables;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class TestTableController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    return view('testtable');
}


public function getTestTable(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = DB::table('transactions')->get();
        return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $actionBtn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>';
                return $actionBtn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }
}
}
```

This my route.

```
Route::get('testtable', [TestTableController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('testtable/list', [TestTableController::class, 'getTestTable'])->name('testtable.list');
```

View/blade.

```
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <h2 class="mb-4">Laravel 7|8 Yajra Datatables Example</h2>
    <table class="table table-bordered yajra-datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Charge</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"> 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

var table = $('.yajra-datatable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "{{ route('testtable.list') }}",
    columns: [
        {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
        {data: 'amount', name: 'amount'},
        {data: 'charge', name: 'charge'},
        {
            data: 'action',
            name: 'action',
            orderable: true,
            searchable: true
        },
    ]
});

});
</script>
```

This is the error from laravel debugbar.

[image: Text]

But the query did have results.

This is the output if I echo the query.

```
$data = DB::table('transactions')->get();
echo $data;
```

[image: Text]

Anything else I'm missing? The exact same code is working if I tested in a new fresh laravel installation. This is an existing project that I try to implement datatables. I guess there must be something from current project configuration that causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in `getTestTable` function look fine. You got in the debugbar:

> **No query results for model [App\Frontend] testtable**

But the code in `getTestTable` has nothing related to `testtable` so I guess `route('testtable.list')` doesn't get to that function. And the reason may be because you put a route like `Route::get('testtable/{id}',...` before `Route::get('testtable/list',` so when you call `testtable/list`, it will take `list` as `id` and go to other function.

If my guess is true, you can fix it by putting `testtable/list` before `testtable/{id}` route.

Comment: Thanks @Cuong Le Ngoc. This answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I share full details with Sample Code from my Project, this below Example code is a Manage Role DataTable from my project. please refer step by step & try to understand it.

first of all you need to **install Laravel Yajra DataTable** using below Composer command

> composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle

then after Define Routes in web.php as like my sample code

```
Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\RoleController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.roles.index');  //index all the data view...

Route::post('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\RoleController::class, 'getIndexUsers'])->name('admin.roles.getIndexRoles');  //Get Users for Laravel Yajra Datatable Index Page record...
```

then after create view file for it, I share sample from my project

```
<div class="card-body">
   <table id="role_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped w-100">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>No.</th>
             <th>Role Name</th>
             <th>Role Slug</th>
             <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
                  
       <tfoot>
            <tr>
               <th>No.</th>
               <th>Role Name</th>
               <th>Role Slug</th>
               <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
       </tfoot>
   </table>
</div>
<!-- /.card-body -->
```

& in Footer Script define Function for Initialize the DataTable like below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataTable = $('#role_table').DataTable({
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        order: [],
        searchDelay: 500,
        "scrollX": "auto",
        "responsive": true,
        // "lengthChange": false,
        "autoWidth": true,
        ajax: {
            url: '{{ route("admin.roles.getIndexRoles")}}',
            type: 'post',
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
          data: function (data) {
                // data.fromValues = $("#filterUserType").serialize();
            },
        },
        columns: [
            {data: 'SrNo', //try with data: 'SrNo' OR data: 'id',
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    // return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                    return meta.row + 1;
                }, searchable: false, sortable: false
            },
            {data: 'role_name', name: 'role_name'},
            {data: 'role_slug', name: 'role_slug'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', searchable: false, sortable: false},
        ],
    });
  </script>
```

then after In your Controller **load Yajra DataTable Class** for use it

> use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables; //for Laravel DataTable JS...

Now, create Function for Display View File like this,

```
public function index()
{
    return view('admin.roles.index');
}
```

Now I crated Function method for Ajax Request for DataTable Initialize

```
public function getIndexUsers(Request $request)
{
    $roles = Role::select('roles.*');
    if($request->order ==null){
        $roles->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }
    $detail_data = $roles;
    return Datatables::of($detail_data)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($data) {
            return $this->DataTableAction($data);
        })
    ->rawColumns(['action'])
    ->make(true);
}

public function DataTableAction($data){
    $btn = '<div class="btn-group">';
        if($data->id == "1" || $data->id == "2"){
            $btn .= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle ml-2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" disabled>Action
                </button>';
        }else{
            $btn .= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle ml-2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action
                    </button>';
        }
            $btn .= '<div class="dropdown-menu">';
            $btn .= '<a class="dropdown-item" href="'.route('admin.roles.edit',$data->id).'" style="color: black;" onmouseover=\'this.style.background="#dee2e6"\' onmouseout=\'this.style.background="none"\'><i class="far fa-edit text-primary"></i> Edit</a>';
            $btn .= '<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>';
            $btn .= '<a role_id="'.$data->id.'" class="dropdown-item deleteRole" href="#" style="color: black;" onmouseover=\'this.style.background="#dee2e6"\' onmouseout=\'this.style.background="none"\'><i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i> Delete</a>';
    $btn .= '</div>
        </div>';
    return $btn;
}
```

**Important Note:-** Currently I use **Laravel 8** So, It's not necessary to needs to define **Yajra Service Provider Class in config/app.php** . But if you are getting any error in your different Laravel version then you wil needs to define Yajra Service Provider Class in config/app.php... for define it follow below steps

**

> **Note that, below step not compulsory, its depends on your Laravel
> version**

**

> config/app.php

```
.....
'providers' => [
    ....
    Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,
]
'aliases' => [
    ....
    'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
]
.....
```

then Run below Command

> php artisan optimize

then if you get any problem, try to Clear Cache using

> **php artisan cache:clear**

> **Important Note:-** If you define Service Provider Class in config/app.php & run optimize command, then **May be** Laravel will load it in autoload which is automatically called when your code references a class or interface that hasn't been loaded yet, ***I'm not sure***

Comment: Hi @Harsh Patel,

Comment: @IzzatZ. Say what you find problem or error?

Comment: Thanks Patel. 

Yes my problem has been solved. Thanks to @Cuong Le Ngoc

Answer (score 0):

if everything is ok in the app codes,
you may loosed config for yajra..
so to configure it, you can go to the config folder in the app root directory and then open app.php file from there and add this line to the provider..

```
Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class
```

the result will be something like this:

```
    'providers' => [
     ..
     .. 
     ..
Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,
    ]
```

and also add this line to the aliases:

Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class

try like this:

```
'aliases' => [
 ..
 ..
 ..
 ..
 'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
]
```

finally, save the file(config\app.php) like above and then open up cmd or terminal and try to clear the app cached file(that includes the config cache) using the fallowing command:

```
php artisan optimize
```